# how to add all dependencies of my lib using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I want to add all dependencies of my lib using cmake.

1. How to use tools to collect all dependency into one package? cpack? Can you give me some examples?
2. How to combine all dependency into my lib. So that I just give others one lib(my lib) and everything's fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is quite general. Maybe have a look at https://rix0r.nl/blog/2015/08/13/cmake-guide/ for an idea how to do what you intend to.

Comment: for example, I have to compile  a  library I wrote say mylib1. Mylib1 depends on many libraries. Maybe opencv protobuf... 1. I want to collect all these libraries so that I can give to others. 2. I may want to combine all of these libraries into one big library. Thus I only need to give just one library to others. How can I achieve that?